# Can't escape dot character in translation messages

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, translation, twig

I want to translate a finished web page and I've followed this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/eiqd_g

When I try to translate this string in a twig template:

```
'Bienvenido a Itransformer.es'
```

like this:

```
{{ 'Bienvenido a Itransformer.es'|trans|raw }}
```

This is supposed to escape the string ([Symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-filters)), but it doesn't.

When I do:

```
php app/console translation:extract en --bundle=MSDHomeBundle --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=yml --exclude-dir=Tests
```

I get the next file `message.en.yml`:

```
'Bienvenido a Itransformer':
    es: 'Bienvenido a Itransformer.es'
```

while I expect to see:

```
'Bienvenido a Itransformer.es':'Welcome to Itransformer.es'
```

Anyone know what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaping the docs are talking about is the escaping when printing on a browser. E.g. if you have a HTML tag in your text, when you are escaping it isn't rendered as tag, but just as plain text.

Please note that using the `|raw` filter, you are *not* escaping. Escaping is on by default, but when using that filter it's switched off.

---

To answer your question. The dot character is used in [keyword messages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#message-placeholders). That's why the translation extracter assumes you are using keyword messages instead of real messages.

You can just change it to `'Bienvenido a Itransformer.es':'Welcome to Itransformer.es'`. The config dumped by the extractor should also work without a problem, as Symfony is adding the dot itself.

Comment: Thank you. And how could I escape `'` symbol in: `'I'll do whatever'`.

Comment: Well, I've achieved replacing `'I'll do whatever'` with `"I'll do whatever"`

Answer (score 1):

For your question about escape `'` character.

I use double in my messages.en.yaml:

```
I_M_HERE: 'I''m here'
```